# nginx returning TLS error on large files

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have NextCloud 15 running on a DigitalOcean Kubernetes cluster. When I download a large (>1GB) file, I get an error. I appear to have narrowed it down to nginx, and I'm wondering how to fix it. Details follow:

## Setup (how the request is routed)

- DigitalOcean LoadBalancer
- nginx Service (a Kubernetes LoadBalancer)
- ingress-nginx pods (3) doing TLS termination/reverse proxy
- nextcloud Service (a Kubernetes Service)
- nextcloud pod

## What happens:

`curl -u [redacted] https://[redacted]/[path to large file]`
Eventually, after several hundred MB  of success, I get the following from `curl`:

```
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

If I set up a `kubectl port-forward` to the NextCloud service or pod, and point `curl` at that, the download succeeds. There are no stalls that would cause a timeout upstream. So it's not NextCloud or its service.

If I set up a `kubectl port-forward` to the nginx service or pod, and point `curl` at that, I get the same result as if I pointed to the DigitalOcean LoadBalancer (`A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.`). So it's likely nginx causing the issue.

## Configuration

nginx is running TLSv1.2, nothing exotic in a run by SSLLabs. It's version nginx/1.15.6. I have turned off `proxy-buffering` through an ingress annotation and verified that it updated the `nginx.conf` with `proxy_buffering  off;` for that virtual host. There are no errors in the nginx logs. The time elapsed and amount of data downloaded varies from run to run.

I saw some chatter online about nginx having issues with HTTP/2, so I re-tried these tests using HTTP/1.1. Same results. Smaller files and the web UI work fine, but downloading large files through `curl`, the web UI, or the nextcloud client are broken.

Is there some known issue with nginx? The same system used to work with Apache on Docker, and only came up when I migrated to nginx on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded `nginx-ingress-controller` deployment to `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.22.0`, which includes nginx/1.15.8, and the problems went away. See the [Changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/Changelog.md) for specifics.